# Can I use a wildcard certificate for the 2nd-level domain itself?

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have a let's encrypt wildcard certificate for `*.the-grue.de`

Is it possible to use that certificate for `the-grue.de` itself? Or do I have to use another certificate?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't use this certificate to secure 2nd level domain. In order to secure the domain name itself and hosts within the domain, you need to get certificate with the following names in SAN extension:

```
DNS Name=example.com
DNS Name=*.example.com
```

first entry secures the domain, second entry secures hosts within domain.